# Dropbox API file upload "WriteMode" not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api

Im using the Dropbox API to upload files using the code below:

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + DROPBOX_API_TOKEN,
        'Dropbox-API-Arg': "{\"path\": \"/test/" + req.file.originalname + "\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }, body: fs.createReadStream(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`, {highWaterMark: 256 * 1024})
};
```

As you can I have settings as:

1. **Mode** = add
2. **Auto rename** = true

What I want is that if a **file already exists** when uploading a file, add the file anyway and rename is like **"document(2).txt"**

**The issue:**

For some reason this functionality is not constant! Dropbox sometimes renames the file if it exists and uploads it and sometimes it doesn't. I can't figure out what's causing this. It should be constant no matter what type of file it is.

**Please note:** I am also creating shareable link after uploading a file and obviously if shareable link already exists for a file I get that.

**Update:**

Http Response for the upload call that isn't working as expected:

```
{"name": "Screen Shot 2018-01-09 at 15.35.16.png", "path_lower": "/test/screen shot 2018-01-09 at 15.35.16.png", "path_display": "/test/Screen Shot 2018-01-09 at 15.35.16.png", "id": "id:i5gw5e4a2xkAAAAAAALbLQ", "client_modified": "2018-01-18T11:16:23Z", "server_modified": "2018-01-18T11:16:23Z", "rev": "30c1e0c16e2cb", "size": 276546, "content_hash": "08da3b75a51211967932b34d93e2dc09c54040efd1ec7dfa9c4ed04928cf4873"}
```

If you look at the `server_modified` field you can see I can uploaded this image this morning at **11:16**. Yet when I upload it again now it did not upload another renamed version of this.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't rename and upload as expected? Please share the unexpected error or output.

Comment: @Greg thats the thing. I don't get any error. My process is **First Upload File** and **Second Create Share Link** and send that link to the user. I don't think the upload happens because I can see the last time the file was modified and the time does not change. But I still get the "share link" back. So I'm guessing it sees the file already exists but it doesn't upload it again with a rename. does this make sense?

Comment: What HTTP response do you get back for the upload API call that isn't working as expected?

Comment: @Greg Please see my updates on the questions for the HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks! That indicates that the upload succeeded. If the metadata didn't change, it's likely because you're uploading the same data as the data that already existed. Is that the case? From the [/2/files/upload documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload): "If the target path refers to a file with identical contents, nothing gets written; no conflict."

Comment: @Greg Apologies for the delayed response. You are correct the files I am uploading has the same data. No content within the file has changed at all. So what you're saying is that only time Dropbox will rename and upload the file that already exists is if that file content has been updated/edited?

Comment: That's correct.